# How to protect vps data from datacenter administrator

Tags: boot, hard-drive, vdi

The data center admin has access to the HDD file. (VDI file or etc)
How to access VPS data only by having root password and operating system(linux)?

Comment: Please provide OS/release details. Linux strictly refers to the kernel (used by many OSes including Android), so please clarify with OS/release details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible.

The data center admin is looking from above the filesystem. If they want they could clone your system, and reset your admin password. All without you ever knowing about it. Not even encrypting the filesystem is going to help you here.

If you have data you do not want someone else to see you do store it somewhere else. On an external media or your own personal system. That way you can encrypt it making sure there is nobody able to see the contents.

Comment: How is encryption not going to help?

Comment: @Sebastian These things work with containers. An admin that is looking from that point of view can activate a keylogger and you'd never know. Data inside a data center is secure by the grace of the owner of that data center.